# Does the Ethereum world state stored into DB every time when the block is mined?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, blocks, state-trie

The Ethereum block header stores the root hash of the world state trie, Does this means every time the state of world state is copied into levelDB for every block mined? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention leveldb probably you want to known about the go-ethereum implementation.

We could say that in old geth versions the state was saved to disk after every block, but only the modified branches of the tree were saved. The unmodified branches remained unchanged in disk.

More recently geth implemented different mechanism to minimize the disk operations. The modified branches remain in memory until a threshold was achieved or a certain time did elapse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. could you let me any blog post that speaks about this or around this topic because I couldn't find much resources on google.

Comment: @Ranjith Sorry, but I don't have more resources that reading the go-ethereum source code, github issues, and release notes.